# Problem with time series plot- Twitter analysis

Tags: python, matplotlib, twitter, time-series

I'm trying to plot a time series plot to show the number of tweet per minute over a particular one hour time period. I have a problem with the x-axis entries as it looks gibberish. Can you please help me solve this issue ?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
plt.plot(list(timedict.keys()), list(timedict.values()))
plt.xlabel('minute', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('tweets number', fontsize=12)
plt.xlim([1,20])
plt.xticks(list(timedict.keys()), fontsize=15, rotation=90)
plt.title('Number of tweets at each minute', fontsize = 20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you explicitly provide the xticks? Also, no screenshot of the code please.

Comment: Yes, the problem was with the xticks statement. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you have many 'ticks' on the x axis... You could space them by doing something like:

```
minuteLength = 1
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(timedict.keys()), max(timedict.keys())+1, minuteLength))
```

Don't forget to adjust the value of minuteLength to a reasonable interval from your dictionary...

Comment: Thank you so much, this works pretty well. Can you please tell me more about the minuteLength variable ? All my tweets were obtained in a one hour interval and it would be great if i get the numbers 10,20,30,40,50,60 in my x-axis.

Comment: Update: Changed the xlim variable and got it changed. Thank you again.

Comment: it basically defines how many ticks you will have on the x axis.. if your interval is 60 minutes and you want them spaced at every ten minutes, i'd use minuteLength=10. (meaning that for every 10 minutes, you will have 1 tick).... does this makes sense?